# Start application from Matlab

Tags: linux, matlab

I'm looking for a way to start an application from within Matlab. The thing is, my Matlab script saves some results to a file, which should then be opened in the associated application (Blender in this case).

I'm familiar with commands like

```
system('program_name')
```

or

```
!program_name
```

and some other ways, but the thing is, the application is started with the Matlab PATH, so it looks inside the Matlab directory for all kinds of libraries it needs. For instance:

```
>> !blender
blender: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by blender)
```

Is there some way to start an application, which uses the global (system) PATH?

A moment ago I thought I found a tweak, namely starting a terminal from within Matlab, with some arguments (Blender filename.blend).

```
system('terminal -x blender /home/pieter/Red.blend')
```

This did work a couple of times, but now I'm getting errors after executing this command 20 times or so...

```
>> system('terminal -x blender /home/pieter/Red.blend')
(terminal:10982): GLib-CRITICAL **: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support
(terminal:10982): Terminal-CRITICAL **: Failed to parse regular expression pattern 0: PCRE library is compiled without UTF8 support
```

I'm using Arch Linx, by the way.

---

**Edit**:

Well, I just thought of a rather dirty solution. Matlab uses the environment variable

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For the paths to the necessary libraries:

```
getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/i386/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/i386
```

So I could save this information to a variable (e.g. **MatlabPath**):

```
MatlabPath = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

and then before I call blender do this:

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',getenv('PATH'))
```

Which makes Matlab use my system libraries. Then after the program has started, re-assign the old value to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',MatlabPath)
```

So... it is a solution, but if anybody knows a cleaner way of solving the problem, let me know.

Comment: What you wrote in "edit" is the best solution that I know. You can also edit your mexopts.sh file to set the environnement variables as you like at each start.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll write something down. I have another related question, how to start an application **with one or more arguments** (like a variable filename) such that the application runs **outside** of Matlab? I mean, **!program_name &** does that for an application (*adding the ampersand does so*), but how can I add the arguments? Is something similar possible with **system('program_name')**...?

Comment: Does spawning another shell work if you use shell instead of the terminal application? I.e. `system(['bash -c ' commandStr])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I indicated in my Edit above, this could be a solution:

```
% Save library paths
MatlabPath = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
% Make Matlab use system libraries
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',getenv('PATH'))
disp('Starting Blender...')
system( ['blender ', Directory, FileName, '.blend'] )
% Reassign old library paths
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',MatlabPath)
```

However, with the other way to start an application, you can immediately return to Matlab after starting it:

```
% Start Blender and immediately return to Matlab
!blender Geometry.blend &
```

The ampersand (**&**) is the key to immediately return to Matlab after starting the application , but starting Blender this way I cannot provide a variable FileName like I can do with **system(...)**.

So, anybody got a clue on how to

- use **!program_name** with a variable filename

  or
- use **system(program_name)** with an option such that Matlab just starts the application (and doesn't wait with returning until the application has been closed)

Answer (score 0):

Just run command in **MATLAB**:

> > setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',[getenv('PATH') getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')])

It appends matlab library in system library.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually clear out the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable in your system call, like this:

```
system('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=; blender');
```

(Note that this most likely depends on the command syntax of the shell that's launched internally by MATLAB. The above should work for Bash).