# The same cmd work in shell but not in subprocess.Popen() for a matlab-based java program under Django

Tags: java, python, django, apache, matlab

Background: Ubuntu 64bit machine. I need to call a matlab-based jar from django(deployed on apache). Here is the problem, when I run the command on the shell, it works; however, when I call `subprocess.Popen({{cmd}})` inside django code, an exception is thrown.
**Edit**: I try to open a python shell and call `subprocess.Popen({{cmd}})`. I write a single python script file and put the same code in it. They all work. It's so weird that the code just fail when run on django!!!!!!
**For details:**

**The cmd: java -jar A.jar param1 param2 param3 param4**
When run directly in shell, everything is normal. When run with python code, the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getProxyLibraryDir(MCRConfiguration.java:178)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:87)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getMCRRoot(MCRConfiguration.java:92)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ModuleDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:66)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getModuleDir(MCRConfiguration.java:71)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1466)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaMCRFactory.newInstance(AutoBlockJavaMCRFactory.java:83)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaMCRFactory.newInstance(AutoBlockJavaMCRFactory.java:94)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory$3.call(AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.java:95)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory$3.call(AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.java:93)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.getInstance(AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.java:72)
    at autoBlockJava.AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.newInstance(AutoBlockJavaSharedMCRFactory.java:93)
    at autoBlockJava.manualMain.<init>(manualMain.java:97)
    at autoblock.AutoBlock.main(AutoBlock.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.get(MCRConfiguration.java:143)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:173)
    ... 15 more
```

I'm totally confused. I really don't know what's the reason for it now.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with environment variables. Verify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `XAPPLRESDIR` to be available calling `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` via `subprocess.Popen(...)`

Comment: Please check my update. Calling the program from python shell and running a single python script file both work. It just doesn't work under django.

Comment: I've tried to call `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` within python code. If I write a python file and directly run it, it prints the right path. However, when the code is put in django, it prints nothing, which means it cannot read the path. That's my assumption. My configuration of django is WSGI and APACHE.

Comment: There are often problems with calling external programs from Matlab, which are related to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Executing `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')` within Matlab often solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved by adding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside wsgi script.

Comment: @A.Donda : you should formulate this as an answer so firstparyer can close the question as "answered".

Comment: @tutuDajuju: True, done.....

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem has nothing to do with Python, Django, or Java, but only with the way Matlab calls external programs.

On Linux, Matlab sets the  variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment of child processes. As an example, on my system:

```
>> getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')

ans =

/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
```

Apparently, this setting makes some system libraries (or just the correct version of glibc?) unavailable to child processes:

```
>> !konsole
konsole: /opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0)
konsole: /opt/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstreams.so.0)
```

The problem can be resolved by explicitly unsetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

I'm not sure for what purpose Matlab sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and I'd guess that some special functionality must be broken by unsetting it. However, I've had the line above in my `startup.m` for years now, and I haven't run into any problems.

See also: [Start application from Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340818/start-application-from-matlab)