# Error While running Rscript (R version 3.2 and Rstudio version 0.99.441 ) through Scilab5.4.1 using unix_w()

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, rstudio, scilab

In Scilab I am using `unix_w()` to run Rscript and the R code  is executing fine  while on the terminal but gives an error while using it with `unix_w()` inside scilab.

(Note: this code runs well in scilab in my laptop which has 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 but gives me this error in my desktop which has 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04)

I have tried debugging my code by writing a file before and after this R command which seems to be the culprit.

```
 library("cluster", lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/library") 
  or
  library("cluster")
```

The error I am seeing is :

```
!--error 10000 
unix_w: The command failed with the error code "1" and the following message:
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /home/binilab/scilab-5.4.1/lib/thirdparty/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.4.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3)
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Loading required package: stats
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /home/binilab/scilab-5.4.1/lib/thirdparty/libgcc_s.so.1: version GCC_4.4.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3)
Error: package ‘stats’ could not be loaded
Execution halted
at line      51 of function unix_w called by :
```

Comment: this solution worked for me!!!                                                (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340818/start-application-from-matlab )